# Can we calculate Z-score for any distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, z-score

Is z-score only confined to normal distribution or can it be used for any distribution

Comment: Sure you can.  Calculate the mean, calculate the sd, and there you are with the z-score.  You just can't use these scores to get probabilities of observations belonging to a normal distribution... because you already know that they're not from a normal distribution.

Comment: in large samples, by virtue of the central limit theorem, you will be able to use the normal distribution in most cases, though

Answer (score 3):

**Not always, but most of the time:** In order to calculate a z-score for a sample, you need to have a non-zero sample variance, which requires that at least one of the values is different to the others.  Given a sample $x_1,...,x_n$ from a distribution, so long as you have a non-zero sample variance, the z-score for each sample value is:

$$z_i = \frac{x_i - \bar{x}_n}{s_n}.$$

For some distributions there is a non-zero probability that you will get all sample values being equal, which would give you a sample variance of zero.  If you use a point-mass distribution then this occurs almost surely, so it is even worse!  In the case where all sample values are equal it is not possible to obtain z-scores for the values.

(In this answer, I am assuming that when you refer to the z-score you are referring to standardisation using the sample, not the true moments of the distribution.  If you are referring to a z-score standardised by the true moments then the same basic principle applies --- i.e., you can only get a z-score if the distribution has a non-zero, non-infinite variance.)

Comment: does it hold to perform on a zero inflated variable e.g. `x <- c(rep(0, 1000), 1:15); scale(x)` too? I'm guessing not, what could be done in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The z-score is a variable that is centered and reduced ie

`X` your variable according to the distribution
$\mu$ your mean and `V` your deviance

$$Z = \frac{(X - \mu)}{\sqrt{V}}$$

You can use estimators for both $\mu$ and `V`

So yes, it can be used for any distribution as long as you have both the mean and deviance

Note : In case `V = 0`, `Z` is not well defined.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not fully correct.  In the case where $V=0$ the formula for $Z$ is not well-defined.  To avoid down-votes, it might be a good idea to revise to note this exception.